# mutate column in R: subtract values from column based on another column condition

Tags: r, dplyr

*I'm sorry for the vague question title and because of my inability to think of a concise question name I might have missed an answer that already exists. If someone has a title suggestion I'm happy to edit!*

(1) I have a dataframe with id's, values, and a baseline column which is either blank or `Y` (2) I want to filter the dataframe based on the outliers then create a table with the outlier values AND a column which subtracts the value from the baseline, per id.

```
set.seed(42)
test <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)),
                   values = rnorm(15, 1.5),
                   baseline = rep(c("Y", "", "", "", ""), 3))
```

## Data Frame:

Three unique IDs, each with their own baseline values.

```
   id     values baseline
1   A  2.1359504        Y
2   A  1.2157471         
3   A -1.1564554         
4   A -0.9404669         
5   A  2.8201133         
6   B  1.1933614        Y
7   B -0.2813084         
8   B  1.3280826         
9   B  2.7146747         
10  B  3.3951935         
11  C  1.0695309        Y
12  C  1.2427306         
13  C -0.2631631         
14  C  1.9600974         
15  C  0.8600051
```

## Current Output

I haven't mutated for the third, new column here

```
test %>% filter(values > (1.5*IQR(test$values)))
```

## The id's and values that are outliers

```
id   values     baseline
A    2.820113         
B    2.714675         
B    3.395193
```

## Desired Output

Per patient, get the value where `baseline == "Y"` then subtract that value from the values column.

```
id   values    v-baseline
A    2.820113  0.6841626   #2.820113-2.1359504  values - A baseline       
B    2.714675  1.521314    #2.714675-1.1933614  values - B baseline
B    3.395193  2.201832    #3.395193-1.1933614  values - B baseline
```

I know this is possible I think my main issue was my inability to properly google the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `id` and then calculate values relative to the baseline value for each `id`. For the outlier filtering, I've selected rows where `values` is less than the overall 25th percentile or greater than the overall 75th percentile, which seemed to be what you were aiming for. However, you can, of course, tweak this to meet your specific needs.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(v_baseline = values - values[baseline=="Y"]) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(values < quantile(values, probs=0.25) |
           values > quantile(values, probs=0.75))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also want to include the baseline value as a column - how would I do that? mutate(baseline = values[baseline == "Y"]) is a bit off....

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by "a bit off".

Comment: Hmm... it works for the dummy dataframe I created for the repex but I'm getting the error "Error: Column `baseline` must be length 500 (the group size) or one, not 34" any insight? I can try to reproduce the error...

Comment: Can you paste into your question the output of `str(df)` (where `df` is the name of your real data frame) and the exact code you ran to get the error?